# Leave a pmt cell blank until data is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am making a spreadsheet with the pmt function. I want the cell with the pmt to remain blank until interest rate, time, and pv is entered.

I have the pmt formula: =PMT(C2/12,C3,C4) And I do not want the #NUM! to appear when there is no data entered in the interest rate (C2), time (C3), or pv (C4) cells. I would like for the monthly payment to remain blank until data is entered.

Comment: What is happening now? What is your current formula? Can you please edit this information into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Excel 2013...

If you want it to display $0.00, use the following:

> =IF(ISERROR(PMT(C2/12,C3,C4)),,PMT(C2/12,C3,C4))

If you want it to appear as empty, use the following:

> =IF(ISERROR(PMT(C2/12,C3,C4)),"",PMT(C2/12,C3,C4))

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!